# AVR ATMEGA328 is Resetting when (TIMER1_CAP_VECT)Interrupt Occurs and sometime with the UART interrupt

Tags: c, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I configure the ICP1 to get the pulses but when it happens, the avr is resetting,
sometimes when the uart iterrput occurs it also reset.
I don't know where I'm missing, I think it could be the fact that I'm using a Makefile not the AVR-STUDIO, but I use Linux.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "display.h"
#include "memoria.h"
#include "pcf8574.h"
#include "lcdpcf8574.h"
#include "uart_hal.h"

#define ON 1
#define OFF 0
#define BOMBA DDD7
#define LDVD DDD6
#define LDVM DDD5
#define TRIGGER DDD2

#define BAUDRATE 9600

void rotina_da_bomba();
void bomba_state(bool state);
void led_verde_state(bool state);
void led_vermelho_state(bool state);
void monta_mensagem(char *mensagem);
void monta_resposta();

caixa_dagua caixa;

bool encher = false;
long dist;

int main(void)
{
    char mensagem_lcd[33] = " ";
    /* configure timer1 in normal mode */
    TCCR1A = 0;
    /* configure icr on rising edge with noise filter */
    TCCR1B = _BV(ICES1) | _BV(ICNC1) | _BV(CS10);
    TIMSK1 = _BV(ICIE1);
    // LED VERMELHO // LED VERDE   // BOMBA
    DDRD = _BV(BOMBA) | _BV(LDVD) | _BV(LDVM) | _BV(TRIGGER); // Configura Saida do LED e da Bomba
    lcd_init(LCD_DISP_ON);
    lcd_puts("   Iniciando      Equipamento");
    _delay_ms(500); // busy wait, 500ms
    lcd_clrscr();

    lcd_puts("  Lab:Sistemas    Embarcados");
    _delay_ms(500); // busy wait, 500ms
    lcd_clrscr();

    ler_informacoes_salvas(&caixa);

    uart_init(BAUDRATE, OFF); // inicia a comunicação bluetooth com um ponteiro de flag para saber se chegou dado
    sei();
    uart_send_string("Iniciando Bluetooth\n");
    caixa.altura_atual = 200;

    while (1)
    {
        char mensagem_bluetooth[50] = ""; // Estou sempre zerando essa variavel
        char resposta[50] = "";

        PORTD |= _BV(PORTD2);
        _delay_ms(10);
        PORTD &= ~_BV(PORTD2);

        uart_send_string("Teste Bluetooth");
        rotina_da_bomba();

        if (uart_read_count()) // Chegou mensagem Bluetooth
        {
            uart_get_string(&mensagem_bluetooth);
            uart_send_string(mensagem_bluetooth);
        }

        monta_mensagem(&mensagem_lcd); // Montando  que será exibida no LCD
        lcd_clrscr();
        lcd_puts(mensagem_lcd);

        _delay_ms(250); // busy wait, 500ms
    }
    return 1;
}

ISR(TIMER1_CAP_VET)
{
    static long temp = 0;
    if (TCCR1B & _BV(ICES1))
        temp = ICR1;
    else
        dist = ((ICR1 - temp) * 1e6) / F_CPU / 5.8;
    TCCR1B ^= _BV(ICES1);
}
```

Here is my Makefile

```
FILENAME   = app/main
FILENAME2  = app/display
FILENAME3  = app/uart_hal
FILENAME5  = app/memoria
FILENAME6  = app/twimaster
FILENAME7  = app/pcf8574
FILENAME8  = app/lcdpcf8574
PORT       = /dev/ttyACM*
DEVICE     = atmega328p
PROGRAMMER = arduino
BAUD       = 115200
COMPILE    = avr-gcc -Wall -Os -mmcu=$(DEVICE)


all: compile upload clean

compile:
    $(COMPILE) -c $(FILENAME).c -o $(FILENAME).o
    $(COMPILE) -c $(FILENAME2).c -o $(FILENAME2).o
    $(COMPILE) -c $(FILENAME3).c -o $(FILENAME3).o
    $(COMPILE) -c $(FILENAME5).c -o $(FILENAME5).o
    $(COMPILE) -c $(FILENAME6).c -o $(FILENAME6).o
    $(COMPILE) -c $(FILENAME7).c -o $(FILENAME7).o
    $(COMPILE) -c $(FILENAME8).c -o $(FILENAME8).o
    $(COMPILE) -o $(FILENAME).elf $(FILENAME).o $(FILENAME2).o $(FILENAME3).o  $(FILENAME5).o $(FILENAME6).o $(FILENAME7).o $(FILENAME8).o
    avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex $(FILENAME).elf $(FILENAME).hex 
    avr-size --format=avr --mcu=$(DEVICE) $(FILENAME).elf

upload:
    avrdude -v -p $(DEVICE) -c $(PROGRAMMER) -P $(PORT) -b $(BAUD) -U flash:w:$(FILENAME).hex:i 
    
    
clean:
    rm $(FILENAME).o
    rm $(FILENAME2).o
    rm $(FILENAME3).o
    rm $(FILENAME5).o
    rm $(FILENAME6).o
    rm $(FILENAME7).o
    rm $(FILENAME8).o
    rm $(FILENAME).elf
    rm $(FILENAME).hex
```

I also have this warning on compilation

```
warning: ‘TIMER1_CAP_VET’ appears to be a misspelled signal handler, missing __vector prefix [-Wmisspelled-isr]
 ISR(TIMER1_CAP_VET)
```

I Change to

```
ISR(TIMER1_CAP_vect)
```

But still resetting

Comment: Start by fixing the warning--it appears to be self explanatory. Is there a define for `TIMER1_CAP_VET` or _is_ it a misspelling? From: https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/AVR_Timer_Interrupts they use: `TIMER1_OVF_vect` At the least, the spelling in the title and your code do _not_ match.

Comment: I see the for the TIMER1 CAP I need to use 
ISR(TIMER1_CAP_vect), but still resetting

Comment: Due to the timer1 typo, it probably wasn't avtive so that leaves the uart ISR. Can you post that? My _guess_ is that an/the ISR is generating a segfault causing the reset

Comment: Why `uart_init(BAUDRATE, OFF);` vs (e.g.) 9600? Can you enable _just_ the uart and get messages?

Comment: Can you run this under a simulation?

Comment: OFF is for highspeed uart void uart_init(uint32_t baud, uint8_t high_speed) , I don't think that UART because I put  it's very recent, and I have this problem since the begin

Comment: I don' t think so, I put this on Tinkercat but they don't  have the handler for TIMER1_CAP_vect. I using the arduino board

Comment: For the moment, forget about other devices. _Prove_ that the uart code is working _without_ anything else. uart is the _first_ device I try to get working. Set your development platform to use 9600 baud and set up the uart similiarly. Consult some uart tutorials that have working code. Verify that you get the first message from the AVR in your devel console. Then, you can increase the baud rate. In your present code, if `uart_send_string` is interrupt driven, because of the _subsequent_ code, you may get a crash before the message comes out. The sim can probably handle the uart, so try it

Comment: I follow your advice and put onlye the code ISR and still getting that warning about the name then I found out the correct name of thee handler is TIMER1_CAPT_vect It's working now

Comment: Bravo! Good luck ... No more resets/crashes? Remember that my first five words in my first comment were: _Start by fixing the warning_ ;-)

Comment: hahahaha I'm  so sorry Thank you so much, the problem was my material the gives me a wrong handler, I spent some times searching the right one, but is finally working

Comment: I guess you've earned a free cup of coffee, or beer :-) or good night's sleep